The sin() function doesn't work in my script for a driver
I used the example in the Blender documentation to write a python script to a driver and it works fine. The example uses val * val as the calculation. When I substitute this with sin(val) it doesn't work.
The sin() function works if I use it in the driver directly but not in a script.
import bpy

def square(val):
    
    return sin(val)

bpy.app.driver_namespace['square' ] = square


What do you mean it doesn't work? Any error messages? Besides, it's math.sin not sin. You have to import math

It runs without error in the text editor but the driver reports "invalid python expression". I tried math.sin and several other variations and no luck, sin() works in the driver.

Ah but driver expressions should work with just sin like here it works https://i.sstatic.net/XI03uoEc.png

Ok, thanks when I add an import math and a math.sin, it works.
